# Upload video en node js que hago mal

Tags: android, android-studio, nodejs, fileupload

tengo un server especial para subir archivos en nodejs q es este

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var multer, storage, path, crypto;
multer = require('multer')
path = require('path');
crypto = require('crypto');

var form = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>" +
"<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
"<input type='file' name='upload'/>" +
"<input type='submit' /></form>" +
"</body></html>";

app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end(form);

});

// Include the node file module
var fs = require('fs');

storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/',filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null,  Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
    /* filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      return crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err);
        }
        return cb(null, "" + (raw.toString('hex')) + (path.extname(file.originalname)));
      });
    } */
  });


// Post files
app.post(
  "/upload",
  multer({
    storage: storage
  }).single('upload'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    /* res.redirect("/uploads/" + req.file.filename); */
    console.log(req.file.filename);
    return res.status(200).end();
  });

app.get('/uploads/:upload', function (req, res){
  file = req.params.upload;
  console.log(req.params.upload);
  var img = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + file);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');

});

port = 4000;
app.listen(port);
console.log("listen on port " + port)
```

y estoy tratando de subir un archivo de video desde android con el codigo q consegui en esta pag

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-video-to-server-using-php/

pero me genera el siguiente error al tratar de enviar el video

> MulterError: Unexpected field
>       at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\ray_c\OneDrive\Documentos\jdserver\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
>       at Busboy. (C:\Users\ray_c\OneDrive\Documentos\jdserver\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
>       at emitMany (events.js:147:13)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:224:7)
>       at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\ray_c\OneDrive\Documentos\jdserver\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
>       at PartStream. (C:\Users\ray_c\OneDrive\Documentos\jdserver\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at PartStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at HeaderParser. (C:\Users\ray_c\OneDrive\Documentos\jdserver\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

tienen alguna idea de q esta sucediendo y como puedo solucionarlo??

Answer (score 0):

Al poco tiempo de subir la pregunta descubri la solucion en esta linea de codigo

```
app.post(
  "/upload",
  multer({
    storage: storage
```

> ```
> >   }).single('upload'), function(req, res) {
> ```

```
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    /* res.redirect("/uploads/" + req.file.filename); */
    console.log(req.file.filename);
    return res.status(200).end();
  });
```

se debia sustituir upload por myFile o al contrario, cambiar el nombre del archivo a subir desde el android, de todas formas ya logre subir un video